# iOS >> CoreData >> How to Save an Array as One Variable?

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data

I have a Data Model object with several properties. In my app, I manage a list of objects with this type. One of the properties in the data model is an array of strings. I wish to save this array via CoreData as one object per each data model object.

How do I do that?

Comment: Convert it into nsdata while saving and return the nsdata from DB and convert it into string again.

Comment: I recommend having a to-many relationship, but you can also save it as data (which is less flexible)